# Laravel Queue Not Working For Sending Mail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I try to send mail on the background but it's not working.

I run php artisan queue:listen and hit the controller for sending mail but it's not received.

After run common php artisan queue:listen its show job in processing.

In jobs, table job entry insert successfully.

.env file

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

Mail File

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class NewOrderSupplierMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.test');
    }
}
```

Job File

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Mail;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer;
use App\Mail\NewOrderSupplierMail;

class SendEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $details;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($details)
    {
        $this->details = $details;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $email = new NewOrderSupplierMail();
        Mail::to($this->details['email'])->send($email);
    }
}
```

Controller File

```
use Mail;
use App\Jobs\SendEmailJob;

$details['email'] = 'sumitsinghnaruka@gmail.com';
dispatch(new SendEmailJob($details));
```

On Terminal

```
php artisan queue:listen database

[2018-09-29 11:27:05][14143] Processing: App\Jobs\SendEmailJob
[2018-09-29 11:27:05][14144] Processing: App\Jobs\SendEmailJob
[2018-09-29 11:27:05][14145] Processing: App\Jobs\SendEmailJob
[2018-09-29 11:27:05][14146] Processing: App\Jobs\SendEmailJob
[2018-09-29 11:27:06][14147] Processing: App\Jobs\SendEmailJob
[2018-09-29 11:27:06][14148] Processing: App\Jobs\SendEmailJob
[2018-09-29 11:27:06][14149] Processing: App\Jobs\SendEmailJob
[2018-09-29 11:27:06][14150] Processing: App\Jobs\SendEmailJob
[2018-09-29 11:27:06][14151] Processing: App\Jobs\SendEmailJob
[2018-09-29 11:27:06][14152] Processing: App\Jobs\SendEmailJob
[2018-09-29 11:27:07][14153] Processing: App\Jobs\SendEmailJob
[2018-09-29 11:27:07][14154] Processing: App\Jobs\SendEmailJob
[2018-09-29 11:27:07][14155] Processing: App\Jobs\SendEmailJob
```

Comment: Try using `queue:work` instead of `queue:listen`

Comment: I try both its show same

Comment: @SumitSingh you should specify with any queue you will dispatch this job, and you should register it after that. please check the official documentation